# Laravel 6 Backpack 4.0: How to get the current page ID in FormRequest class or can I get by without using FormRequest classes?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In my UpdateUserRequest class I have a validation rule that requires using the page ID to exclude the current record from validation. Question is, how can I get the current page ID?

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users_admin,email,'. $page_id,
    ];
}
```

I know how to do it without the FormRequest class basically by just using the `update(Request $request, $id)` method in the controller.

I have tried doing this basic way which is by writing a `update(Request $request, $id)` method in the controller and performing the validations in there. The validation works as expected but then there's another problem of the page wasn't redirecting properly in the Backpack admin after saving.

I actually prefer this basic approach (using `store()` and `update()` methods in the controller) than having to have separate FormRequest classes for create and update validations.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can get the id with the below simple way , i have tried it and it works for me.

```
public function rules()
{
    $page_id = $this->get('id') ?? request()->route('id');
    return [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users_admin,email,'. $page_id,
    ];
}
```

Referenced from the below mentioned url

https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/blob/master/src/app/Http/Requests/UserUpdateCrudRequest.php

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the unique method of the Illuminate\Validation\Rule class:

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required', 
            Rule::unique('post')->ignore(request()->route('id'))
        ],
    ];
}
```

Detailed description in laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: You can get the table name like this:
`request()->route()->controller->crud->model->getTable()`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?